# Rails language persistent? Locale always routing to default_locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, rails-i18n

I recently started to work with Rails and I18n.

It seems that, in my app, when I send an Http request to move from one endpoint to another the selected I18n param is not persistent.

I.e.

*I land on the homepage http://localhost:4000*

*I get redirected to the default language http://localhost:4000/en*

*I click a button "Español" to switch language preference*

*I got sent to http://localhost:4000/es*

*The text on the page is in Spanish*

(So far behaves as expected)

*I click on a button to get to another page of the app i.e. "video"*

*I got redirected to http://localhost:4000/en/video*

*The text on the page is in English*

As can be seen, the language preference "es" is gone and now I got redirected back to the default one "en". My Rails version is 5.1.
Here is my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope ":locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
    root 'pages#home'
    get 'accommodation' => 'pages#accommodation'
    get 'afterparty' => 'pages#afterparty'
    post 'afterparty' => 'pages#create_afterparty'
    get 'afterparty/index' => 'pages#afterparty_index'
    get 'registry' => 'pages#registry'
    get 'rsvp' => 'pages#rsvp'
    post 'rsvp' => 'pages#create'
    get 'rsvp/index' => 'pages#rsvp_index'
    get 'video' => 'pages#video'
  end
  match '*path', to: redirect("/#{I18n.locale}/%{path}"), :via => [:get, :post]
  match '', to: redirect("/#{I18n.locale}"), :via => [:get, :post]
end
```

Here is my application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :set_locale

  private

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] if params[:locale].present?
  end

  def default_url_options(options = {})
    {locale: I18n.locale}
  end

end
```

Here is my locale.rb defined in the initializers directory:

```
# Where the I18n library should search for translation files
I18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('lib', 'locale', '*.{rb,yml}')]

# Permitted locales available for the application
I18n.available_locales = [:en, :es]

# Set default locale to something other than :en
# I18n.default_locale = :es
```

Here is an extract of application.html that shows the locale param assignation:

```
            <%= t('.language') %>
            <%= link_to_unless_current "English", locale: "en" %> |
            <%= link_to_unless_current "Español", locale: "es" %>
```

Here is an extract of application.html that exemplifies 2 of the anchor tags that redirect you to different pages:

```
            <a class="names" href='/'><h4>Christina & Alex</h4></a>
            <a class="section" href='/video'>VIDEO</a>
```

I tried several things unsuccessfully. Please help to clarify where I am wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links and buttons in your application do not appear to carry the locale from `default_url_options` in them.

For instance, your link:

```
<a class="section" href='/video'>VIDEO</a>
```

Does not use the locale param.

If you used the rails helpers, it will:

```
<%= link_to 'VIDEO', video_path, class: 'section' %>
```

Because the `*_path` and `*_url` helpers will merge the `default_url_options`,
and the final HTML will look like this:

```
<a class="section" href='/video?locale=es'>VIDEO</a>
```

Of course, you could add the locale param yourself, too.

Comment: Thanks Unixmonkey!
That was really useful. It makes sense and works. 